# Access tags in JSP one by one

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xpath

I have XML that looks like this

```
<par>
    <subpar>
        <r>...</r>
          ......
        <rz>...</rz>
    </subpar>
</par>
```

par - root tag, it can have a few subpar inside, but inside subpar, it is unknown what tags can be, I mean it is not preset. It can be 2 rz 1r tags or 2 rn and 3 r tags.

In JSP I use

```
<x:parse xml="${requestScope.xml } var="xml"
```

then create loop `<x:forEach select="$xml/subpar">` to iterate over xml subpar's, but how to access every element inside `subpar` one by one, because now I iterate over every tag extra, I mean first `forEach` loop for `r` tags, then for `rz` tags, and it is not very good approach as I need to read tags one by one.

Comment: That's nice - do you a question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat question was there, but html tags hidden it ;P edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<x:forEach select="$xml/subpar">
     <x:forEach select="*">
          ...
     </x:forEach>
</x:forEach>
```